# Cannot login with Opera: Page Not Found

Tags: support, login, opera

I try to login using stack exchange account in Opera. When I click "Submit" button, the placeholder where the login fields were get replaced with:

```
Not Found
This page could not be found.
```

The outer contents, headers and footers, remain same.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/users/login
2. Log in with Stack Exchange
3. Enter login details and submit
4. "Not Found" https://stackoverflow.com/users/login#log-in

Win XP, Opera 11.10, default settings, cookies enabled, no addons, reproduced on 2 machines.

### Update

One system still has this issue. I disabled anti-virus and firewall, tried to login in a private tab (to simulate clean start) and the issue occurred again.

I used Opera's "Inspect" option and found that the login form is displayed in an IFRAME, with source being `https://openid.stackexchange.com/affiliate/form?...`. If I open this URL in a separate window, I can login just fine and get redirected back to where I came from, but if I want to use the normal "Log In" page the "Not Found" problem occurs.

Very confusing...

Comment: Hmm, I can't reproduce this with Opera 11.10 on Windows 7.

Comment: Could you try to downgrade to 11.01 and try with that? I've had a similar problem with 11.10 a while ago...

Comment: I just tried on another machine today and it worked without problems. It is either already fixed or it is a configuration issue on other machines, I'll check that later on.

Comment: Opera... on XP... There always has to be someone.

Answer (score 2):

Clear your cookies and try again.

Check for your DNS settings.

Check your firewall if you use any 3rd party firewall like Zone Alarm.

Check whether your antivirus program is blocking the site.

If the problem still continues, I'll be happy to provide you with more solutions; let me know.