# Cannot login with Firefox 4.0.1: Page Not Found

Tags: support, firefox, login

I observe the same behaviour with Firefox 4.0.1 as described in [Cannot login with Opera: Page Not Found](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92654/cannot-login-with-opera-page-not-found). I use the same procedure and observe the same outcome. It neither works with Firefox started in SafeMode with all add-ons deactivated.

Internet Explorer 9 is OK.

Answer (score 5):

You're exhibiting [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192837/form-being-randomly-submitted-as-get-instead-of-post).  The first person I've actually got "on the line" who has encountered it.

I'm going to go out on a limb and say this is your ISP doing something very... internet-breaky.  IE 9 working (I'm guessing intermittently) is odd, but I can imagine bogus caching rules that would allow it.

Anyway, from your IP address I've logged the following:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache 
Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/webp, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate 
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en;q=0.8 
Cookie: canary=1; anon=[REDACTED]
Host: openid.stackexchange.com 
User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; de) Presto/2.8.131 Version/11.11 
[IP REDACTED]
```

And

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate 
Accept-Language: de-de,de;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,en-us;q=0.4,es;q=0.2 
Host: openid.stackexchange.com 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1 
[IP REDACTED]
DNT: 1
```

Both as `GET`s to `/affiliate/form/login/submit`, which expects `POST`s.  This is very very wrong.  <del>Could you do a traffic capture* to see if this is your browser (for some crazy reason) submitting GETs instead of POSTs, or whether it's a proxy/ISP doing the conversion down the line?</del>

**Confirmed**:  These requests are arriving at our network as `GET`s, but leaving the browser as `POST`.  Tricky...

Also note, that FireFox's "Do Not Track" behavior (what with not accepting cookies, and that `DNT` header) will break this as well.  The `GET` instead of `POST` is just the first thing that explodes.

<sub>*Firebug (or the Opera equivalent, if there is one) would be best, HTTPS makes proper capture a bit of a pain.</sub>

Comment: see his comment to my answer. Frank says there is a POST request from Firebug, that implies it's something modifying it "above" the browser.

Comment: @Jeff - ah, missed the comment.  Fun.  Digging into logs, but every other time I've looked at this its been arriving at our network as a `GET`.

Answer (score 1):

When we see this, it is usually because the browser is misconfigured or has rogue plug-ins.

Try it in Firefox Safe Mode -- hold down <kbd>shift</kbd> while starting the browser:

http://blog.mozilla.com/rstrong/2011/01/21/windows-safe-mode-and-shortcut-changes-for-firefox-4-0-beta-10/

Comment: Funnily, I have no trouble logging-in and -out with Opera 10. Firefox does neither work with all add-ons deactivated. For further testing I created a new Firefox profile. This profile works as long as I restart Firefox. Then I also can no longer log-in with that empty profile. Clearing the cache does also not seem to work. Perhaps this is a Firefox bug.

Comment: According to Firebug there is a post request to https://openid.stackexchange.com/affiliate/form/login/submit which is responded to with 404 Not Found.